# Is it possible to only get a certain predetermined number of combinations in Python?

Tags: python, combinations

First if all, I'm a beginner, so sorry if I cant explain myself correctly. 
I'm brute forcing a project, and using the combination function from itertools. Issue is: The number of combinations in my problem is absurdly large (ca. 10**40), so I don't want to check all of them but only the first f.e. 10000. So how can I program it, such that the combinations function stops after 10000?

Comment: You're looking for [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

Comment: Depends on the length of the cominations you're after, however as @ForceBru suggested, `itertools.islice` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
i = 0 

while i<10000:

   do_something

    i += 1
```

[while loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp)